# change of pH in urine

Tags: acid-base, ph

I'm looking to lower the pH of a urine solution from 12 to 7. I'm planning to do it in 2 ways. First is to use a strong acid such as HCl. Secondly, using vinegar, a weak acid. However, I am having troubles calculating the pH in both methods as it other chemicals in urine such as ammonia may react to it. Since it's a theoretical experiment, can I just assume that the acid would only react to water? But how will I do it either way?

Comment: Urine certainly **does** contain other chemicals (and the content varies wildly, mind you), which certainly **would** react with acid. There is no going around that.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what concentrations of the other chemicals that are present, it is impossible to do a theoretical calculation. The only way to do this would be experimentally.